# was ruby sdk: how to find instances without missing name tag

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk

To list ec2 instances without a name tag, I tried

```
# resource interface
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new
ec2.instances(filters:[{name:'tag:Name', values:[]}]).each do |instance|
   # ...
end
```

Any idea how to do this?

[1] https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=740190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try iterating over all instances the API returns, with an `unless` to catch instances that don't have the tag you're seeking. Operate within that conditional.